# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm brushing up on spring with this [tutorial](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-angular-app-with-java-backend-87fb603c6e17) and getting the following dependency issue on JPARepository:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userPersistence' defined in persistence.UserPersistence defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector
```

The `UserPersistence` class is like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;


@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface UserPersistence extends JpaRepository<UserDAO, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserDAO>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<UserDAO> {}
```

and I'm using this `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '4.4.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Many thanks to anyone with any knowledge about this issue!

Comment: try update spring boot to 2.4.3

Comment: The exception sounds like an dependency issue, it might have happend bcs of this:

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.4.5'

I am not so sure if the data-commons 2.4.5 is compatible with the spring version 2.3.9. Try the approach of glovemobile. If it doesn't work, you should check if the Class is present at: org/springframework/core/

Comment: Updating the spring boot version to 2.4.4 worked, thank you for your help!

Comment: @glovemobile please post your comment as an answer so it an get upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ you should use spring boot 2.4.3. Thanks @Jens Schauder.

Comment: Version 2.4.4 :)

Comment: Your answer is workaround because probably you have some springframework dependency, for example org.springframework:spring-web. So if you want use newer version of spring boot you have to upgrade both spring-boot and springframework.

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me when I changed the spring core version to 5.3.8

I updated the following entry in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
```