# org/springframework/core/NativeDetector java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector issue is comming

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, ava

These are version and dependencies that I am using
I suspect the versions needs to be changed but to what, that is I am not sure

```
        springCore          : '5.3.3',
        springjdbc             : '5.3.3',
        springContext              : '5.3.3',
        springTest            : '5.3.3',
        springWeb              : '5.3.3',
        springWebmvc           : '5.3.3',
        springDataJpa          : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        springBootdataJpa      : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        bootStarterTomcat      : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        bootStarterTest        : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        springBoot             : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        springBootWeb       : '2.3.3.RELEASE',
        

        bootStarterTest        : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$versions.bootStarterTest",
        springWebmvc           : "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$versions.springWebmvc",
        springContext          : "org.springframework:spring-context:$versions.springContext",
        springTest             : "org.springframework:spring-test:$versions.springTest",
        bootStarterTomcat      : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:$versions.bootStarterTomcat",
        springWeb              : "org.springframework:spring-web:$versions.springWeb",
        springDataJpa          : "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:$versions.springDataJpa",
        springBootdataJpa      : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$versions.springBootdataJpa",
        springCore             : "org.springframework:spring-core:$versions.springCore",
        springjdbc             : "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$versions.springjdbc",
        springBoot             : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$versions.springBoot",
        springBootWeb          : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$versions.springBootWeb",
```

I have tried the solution in [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734463/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-core-nativedetector) but still getting the same error.
Also tried the solution in [Spring Boot ClassNotFoundException org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications).
Still no luck

Adding the error stake trace

> org/springframework/core/NativeDetector
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/core/NativeDetector   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:180)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:193)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.(GenericApplicationContext.java:113)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.createContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:210)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:113)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
> at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
> at
> org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
> at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)   at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.core.NativeDetector   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 66 more

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using wrong version so please try to use spring v - 5.3.4 as the class -> org/springframework/core/NativeDetector is present in that version of spring framework.